# High frequency PCB layout

Tags: pcb, altium, design

I am designing a printed circuit board with Sigfox IC ATA8520 from Microchip. The max frequency I have worked with is 20 MHz for PIC microcontrollers. I have been searching for design considerations while layout the board so that I do not have a lot of noise on the board. I am using Altium Designer 19 for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: it is going to be a double sided board

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. That's a broad open ended questions. You will get better answers with a more specific question.

Comment: It's a good idea to upvote your accepted answer. It encourages people who have been helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. The less alternating leads of the pins between the layers of high frequency circuits, the better.

This means that the less Via is used in connection, the better. A Via can bring about a distribution capacitance of about 0.5pF, reducing the number of Via can significantly increase the speed and reduce the possibility of data error.

> 2. The shorter the lead between the pins of high-frequency circuits is, the better it is.

The radiation intensity of the signal is directly proportional to the routing length of the signal line. The longer the high-frequency signal lead is, the more easily it can be coupled to its components. Therefore, for high frequency signal lines such as signal clock, crystal oscillator, DDR data, LVDS, USB and HDMI, the shorter the routing length is required, the better.

> 3. The less bend between the pins of high-frequency electronic devices, the better.

High frequency electrical wiring leads had better use full straight line. If a break over is required, a 45 degree broken line or arc break can be used. This requirement is only used to improve the bonding strength of copper foil in low-frequency circuits, while in high-frequency circuits, meeting this requirement can reduce the external emission and coupling of high-frequency signals.

> 4. Pay attention to the "crosstalk" introduced by the signal line parallel to close distance.

For high frequency circuit wiring, attention should be paid to the "crosstalk" introduced by the signal line parallel in a close distance. Crosstalk refers to the coupling phenomenon between signal lines without direct connection. Since high frequency signals are transmitted along the transmission line in the form of electromagnetic waves, the signal line will act as an antenna, and the energy of electromagnetic field will be emitted around the transmission line. The unwanted noise signals between signals due to the coupling of electromagnetic fields are called Crosstalk. The parameters of PCB plate layer, the spacing of signal lines, the electrical characteristics of driving and receiving terminals and the signal line connection mode all have certain influence on the crosstalk. Therefore, in order to reduce the crosstalk of high frequency signals, it is required to do the following as much as possible in the layout process.

I basically copied this from [here](https://www.pcbway.com/blog/PCB_Design_Layout/High_Frequency_PCB_Layout_Techniques.html) on Altium website.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i was looking for. one last question, how thick should the traces be. I am using a 5V and a 3V3 supply

Comment: Depending on the current those traces will be carrying. But typically i stick to 10-15 mil (imperial) for signal lines and 20 to 50 for power lines depending on the current. Please 'accept' the answer if this answers your question.

Answer (score -3):

A high-frequency Printed Circuit Board can meet your needs when incorporating a special signal requirement into your electronic components and products. It offers a frequency range of 500MHz - 2GHz, making it ideally suited for high-speed designs, as well as radio frequency (RF), microwave and mobile applications. These higher transmission frequencies can also provide the faster signal flow rates that are a necessity in today's increasingly complex electronic switches and other components.
High Frequency Printed Circuit Board is a type of PCB used for signal transmission in the variety of applications including mobile, microwave, radio frequency and high speed design applications.

High Frequency boards come with high frequency laminates are difficult to fabricate because they need to maintain thermal heat transfer of the application, in view of the sensitivity of the signal.

Characteristics of the high frequency board can affect the overall performance of the signal, similarly any change in the Er value of the materials used can widely impact the impedance of the PCB board.

Comment: This is a direct copy from abp.net.cn/tlx-9-pcb-p00102p1.html please make sure you provide a source, indicate which part is your writing and which is not (usually with the paragram or quote button. Edit your question please. Plagiarism is not tolerated on SE

Comment: @Chetan -   While this is closer to plagiarism than not, and does not attribute the original source, its most glaring defect is that it does not really address the actual question. You obviously have skills that are useful in identifying potentially relevant information - quoting small sections from other pages and attributing them is acceptable and preferred to what you have done so far. I'm sure you are able to make a useful contribution here. Following site guidelines will be appreciated. I'll not delete this answer *at this point*. I suggest adding attribution would be a good idea.